# XCode keeps crashing while uploading TestFlight since morning

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, app-store-connect

I did not make any changes in the code and Xcode but Since morning build upload has not working on TestFlights. Tries Apple Transporter as well Build shown as successfully uploaded but not visible on app store connect.

Also XCode crashes since morning this is the 5th time build upload is in progress while app store crashed.

Any anyone facing the same issue and has a solution then let me know.

Any one has idea about to resolve the issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Working now without me doing anything different, just uploaded a build fine.

Same issue, no solution yet. I'm assuming it's Apple's end and we'll be back up soon. Mine likewise worked yesterday, but I have your exact issue today crashing right as it starts to upload, or before then I get one of the following:

- Error 401
- The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEFoundation.DistributionCredentialedProviderLocatorError error 1.) Credentialed provider request failed with error: "Unexpected Status Code"
- Loading testflight in my browser also gave a "we can't process your request" earlier

Tried re-logging in on Xcode, Testflight, Dev portal. No warnings

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because my Apple ID session expired in Xcode. After logging in again, I was able to successfully distribute TestFlight. Please find the screenshot below for your reference.

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEFoundation.DistributionCredentialedProviderLocatorError error 1.) Credentialed provider request failed with error: "Unexpected Status Code"`

[image]